# cakephp 2.x find() or without find()?

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'Restaurant' => $this->Restaurant->geoRest($lat, $lng, $radius1, $limit)
        );
$this->set('restaurants',$this->paginate());
```

The model has a function called geoRest() and some options inside and at the end the following code:
    return $options;

Everything is working fine.

BUT:

What if I want to use find('all', $options) like this in the model:

```
$rests = array();
$rests = $this->find('all', $options);
return $rests;
```

I get an error that says:

```
Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2709]
```

I think I should use find() to have proper cakephp code, right? But what is the correct solution?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the returned value of `geoRest()`?

Comment: Now I know the problem. As far as I found out, I have to use the pagination-methods if I want to have paginateable results. Otherwise It works fine with find('all'...), but without paginate. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you've found the problem, please close your question